# Wordpress Divi - How to change the mobile header to have a button

Tags: php, css, wordpress, mobile

I would like to have a button always showing in my mobile header that says "Sign Up." Currently I can only have 3 dashes, which is the menu. I would instead like to have a button that says sign up in addition to the 3 dashes/menu. Does anyone know how to do that? I am using the Divi theme from Elegant Themes.

Thanks in advance!!

[image: This is what it looks like now]

[image: I would like to add a button like this]

Comment: You may need to edit the PHP file associated with displaying the menu so that you can add the buttons.  The menu "three bars" itself can be hidden using CSS `display:none;`

Comment: Any chance you know how that might be done? I'd like to just add a button next to the 3 bars.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery

use the append function to append the button and use css to position it absolutely. Also hide the button if not on mobile view.

Let me know if you need some help.

Comment: This is probably way over my head to figure out since I don't code. I'll have to find someone to help me with this. But appreciate your response!

Comment: do you still need help?